# Get all string values using for loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

There is a `dict` table:

```
 | ID | Code  | Value |
   +--- +-------+-------+
   | 48 | SUMM  | 47800 |
   | 48 | BIN   | 44788 |
   | 48 | CNL   | BHF55 | 
   | 50 | SRV_L | 88    |
   | 50 | FL_F  | AGI2g |
```

It is necessary in xml to transfer all rows of the table through the loop
**Request:**

```
for ac in (select a.CODE, a.value
             from M_MUNORD_ADD a
           where a.code is not null  
             and a.ID = iId)
loop
    sCod:= ac.code;
    sVal:= ac.value;
end loop;    

cXmlStr:='<Version="2.3">
          <BillCode>ATTRIBUTES</BillCode>
          <Info>
                <Param Id='||sCod||'>'||sVal||'</Param>
          </Info>
```

In Info tags need to transfer all rows of the table by ID
When transmitting to xml it isn't known how many lines will be by code

That is, I expect this result, for example, by Id = 48:

```
<Info>
      <Param Id='SUMM'>'47800'</Param>
      <Param Id='BIN'>'44788'</Param>
      <Param Id='CNL'>'BHF55'</Param>           
 </Info>
```

Now I get the following result:

```
      <Info>
          <Param Id='CNL'>'BHF55'</Param>           
      </Info>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want the single quotes within the element values?

Comment: Why PL/SQL? This can be done quite easily with plain SQL. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c7e1345dcb95ab29bad1984e6e0a68b0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should concatenated the param tags in a Loop, you can try this one:

```
for ac in (select a.CODE, a.value
             from M_MUNORD_ADD a
           where a.code is not null  
             and a.ID = iId)
Loop
    v_params := v_params || '<Param Id="'||ac.code'">'||ac.value||'</Param>';
end loop;    

cXmlStr:='<Version="2.3">
          <BillCode>ATTRIBUTES</BillCode>
          <Info>'|| v_params ||'</Info>';
```

Comment: how to select the first(SUMM  | 47800) element from the loop and write in the tag <Target>'||ac.first||'</Target>??

Answer (score 4):

Use Oracle's XML functions:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE M_MUNORD_ADD ( ID, Code, Value ) AS
 SELECT 48, 'SUMM',  '47800' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 48, 'BIN',   '44788' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 48, 'CNL',   'BHF55' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 50, 'SRV_L', '88'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 50, 'FL_F',  'AGI2g' FROM DUAL
```

**PL/SQL Block**:

```sql
DECLARE
  cXmlStr CLOB;
  iId M_MUNORD_ADD.ID%TYPE := 48;
BEGIN
  SELECT XMLELEMENT(
           "Info",
           XMLAGG(
             XMLELEMENT(
               "Param",
               XMLATTRIBUTES( Code AS "Id" ),
               '''' || Value || ''''
             )
           )
         ).getClobVal()
  INTO   cXmlStr
  FROM   M_MUNORD_ADD
  WHERE  CODE IS NOT NULL
  AND    ID = iID;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( cXmlStr );
END;
/
```

**Output**:

> ```
> dbms_output:
> <Info><Param Id="SUMM">&apos;47800&apos;</Param><Param Id="BIN">&apos;44788&apos;</Param><Param Id="CNL">&apos;BHF55&apos;</Param></Info>
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b522619672ad94c8aeb365acdbb0e680)*

Answer (score 4):

You can use native XML/SQL functions instead of PL/SQL:

```
select xmlelement(
  "Info",
  xmlagg(
    xmlelement("Param", xmlattributes(code as "Id"), value)
  )
)
from dict
where id = 48;

XMLELEMENT("INFO",XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("PARAM",XMLATTRIBUTES(CODEAS"ID"),VALUE)))  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<Info><Param Id="SUMM">47800</Param><Param Id="BIN">44788</Param><Param Id="CNL"
>BHF55</Param></Info>
```

or serialized for readability:

```
select xmlserialize(
  document
  xmlelement(
    "Info",
    xmlagg(
      xmlelement("Param", xmlattributes(code as "Id"), value)
    )
  )
  indent size=2) as result
from dict
where id = 48;

RESULT                                                                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<Info>
  <Param Id="SUMM">47800</Param>
  <Param Id="BIN">44788</Param>
  <Param Id="CNL">BHF55</Param>
</Info>
```

You can include other elements with `xmlconcat`:

```
select xmlserialize(
  content
  xmlconcat(
    xmlelement("xyz", xmlattributes(2.3 as "Version")),
    xmlelement("BillCode", 'ATTRIBUTES'),
    xmlelement(
      "Info",
      xmlagg(
        xmlelement("Param", xmlattributes(code as "Id"), value)
      )
    )
  )
  indent size=2) as result
from dict
where id = 48;

RESULT                                                                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<xyz Version="2.3"/>
<BillCode>ATTRIBUTES</BillCode>
<Info>
  <Param Id="SUMM">47800</Param>
  <Param Id="BIN">44788</Param>
  <Param Id="CNL">BHF55</Param>
</Info>
```

... though that isn't quite what you want the Version to look like, so you may still need to tack that on manually. As this is only a fragment and not a full XML document it isn't entirely clear how that should be done.